# SpringBoot index not read

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using springboot and download these template from the internet. It was supposingly in maven format, but i changed it to gradle.

The problem is that, when i run the application "bootRun", the project compiles without any problem, but it hit the whitelabel error. Any idea where could i go wrong ?

[image]

The image is how the controller is defined, and based on the console log, the "/" is mapped, but when i run it, i am still hitting the error 404.

[image]

The file structure of the application is available on the left hand side of the first picture.

As for the build script, it was originally a pom file, but i had changed it to a gradle build file as below.

[image]

The original pom file is as below:
[image]

Finally, though i think this is will not affect the application, but i attach its code as well, as this initializer is an important part of the app.

[image]

This particular app is using angular as well, but i think it is not the cause of this issue. Since the angular is injected into the index.html, it should have at least found the index.html file instead of 404 rite ?

Just in case this is needed, the index.html is as below:
[image]

Hope some of you could help.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the browser with a slash at the end? (ie `http://localhost:8080/`)

Comment: yea, have tried it. when i put the slash at the end, it will get the same result, and browser will remove the slash. i also tried to put /test in the controller, and at browser i do the same. it is still a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Spring MVC with Thymeleaf.

You do not need any controller to render `index.html` since it is in the `static` folder, which means Spring MVC will render the static resource for you. Just delete the Controller and you are done.

If you really want to render your `index.html` using an MVC controller you must put the `index.html` into `templates`, otherwise Thymeleaf will not find it and you'll get something like this:

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the 
configured Template Resolvers`

Comment: You are right, i need to put the index into a templates folder within resources folder. In a separate note, i am planning to use angularjs for the frontend rendering. But using thymeleaf, it needs everything to be within this folder. Apart from that, all needs to go to the mapping within @controller... it seems contradicting with angularjs routing... any idea ? in my angular route, it won't be able to find the file if i don't include the routing in 'java controller', using thymeleaf... but this will make it double work, one mapping in java controller, another in angular, isn't it ?

Comment: Since I do not know all the details of your project (and as we know the devil is in the details) you may consider using Angular to render the web content coming e.g. from some RESTful API you can implement using Spring Web MVC controllers. This [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/) can probably provide some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot sets up several classpath locations from which it will serve static content; those are: `/META-INF/resources/`,  `/resources/`,  `/static/` and `/public/`

This is configured in `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
    "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
    "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
```

From your first screenshot it looks like your `index.html` file is in `/resources/static/`. Try updating your Controller to return `/static/index`.